# Software to playback inputted music notes

Tags: linux, web-apps, music, music-production

Is there any software (online or download) that allows the user to input a sequence of notes, set the time signature etc. and then choose instrument to hear the notes being played back.

E.g. The user chooses:

```
Notes to be played: CC GG Am AmGFF CC GG F Em Dm C
Time signature: 4/4
BPM: 80
Instrument: Grand Piano
```

and then the software would output the music.

Does anyone know of something?

My OS is Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: May be Hydrogen made for GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I think lmms https://lmms.io/ should fit in your needs. It's a relative simple cross platform music composition software.